# Retrieve only values from Array

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I need to retrieve only the values from an array of a payload, using dataweave in mule.

I have tried using the ++ technique, but it returns errors or when I put the values variable set an an array I get " in the results.

```
Input:
{               
"Shops": 
  [{                    
        "StoreName":    "Store1",
        "Sales": 
                  [{"dayDate":  "01/01/2019",                           
                    "product": "A",                             
                    "quantity": 2
                },
                    {"dayDate": "02/01/2019",                           
                    "product": "B",                             
                    "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
   }]
}
```

I expect the Output:

```
[Store1, [01/01/2019, A, 2], [02/01/2019, B, 1]]
```

but actual is

```
["Store1, [01/01/2019, A, 2], [02/01/2019, B, 1]"]
```

How do I remove the " or if there is a better way of obtaining my expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to get an answer, you'll have to provide more information including code for a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need the `pluck` function, which transforms an object into an array (docs [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-pluck)).

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var shops = {               
  "Shops": [
    {                    
      "StoreName":    "Store1",
      "Sales": [
        {
          "dayDate":  "01/01/2019",                           
          "product": "A",                             
          "quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "dayDate": "02/01/2019",                           
          "product": "B",                             
          "quantity": 1 }]}]}

var res = shops.Shops map (shop) -> 
  using (sales = shop.Sales map (sale) -> sale pluck $)
  [shop.StoreName] ++ sales
---
flatten(res)
```

This goes a bit beyond what you've described so that it can also handle multiple shops. If you need to be able to handle multiple shops, you probably won't want to use `flatten`, but it is there so the output matches what you asked for.

Output:

```
[
  "Store1",
  [
    "01/01/2019",
    "A",
    2
  ],
  [
    "02/01/2019",
    "B",
    1
  ]
]
```